# Divide one column of a data.table by an integer depending on another column in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` in R of the following format:

```
     COHORT      VARTYPE  SUM
  1:     RA          CDS   25
  2:     RA       INTRON 1152
  3:     RA        DONOR    0
  4:     RA     ACCEPTOR    1
  5:     RA TSS-UPSTREAM   98
 ---                         
101:    YRI      DISRUPT    0
102:    YRI  UNKNOWN-INC  979
103:    YRI         MIRB    0
104:    YRI         PFAM    8
105:    YRI     CGA_MIRB    0
```

In the `COHORT` column, there are 5 values. They are `RA`, `Lupus`, `CEU`, `YRI` and `ASW`.

I wish to divide the `DT$SUM` column by a different integer depending on the value of `DT$COHORT`.

Specifically,

```
If DT[COHORT=="RA"]   then  DT$SUM<-(DT$SUM/62)
If DT[COHORT=="Lupus"]   then  DT$SUM<-(DT$SUM/62)
If DT[COHORT=="YRI"]   then  DT$SUM<-(DT$SUM/80)
If DT[COHORT=="CEU"]   then  DT$SUM<-(DT$SUM/96)
If DT[COHORT=="ASW"]   then  DT$SUM<-(DT$SUM/5)
```

However so far the syntax I have has only succeeded in dividing the *entire column* by a given integer, but only the portion of `DT$SUM` having the desired value of `DT$COHORT` should be divided...

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `data.table`, you can, similar to @alexis_laz's answer (+1), create another (lookup) table and just perform a join and recalculate `SUM` as follows:

First we'll generate some data (borrowed and modified a bit from @alexis_laz):

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(101)
dat = data.table(COHORT = sample(c("RA", "Lupus", "YRI", "CEU", "ASW"), 1e5, TRUE), 
                 SUM = sample(100, 1e5, TRUE))
```

Since division will result in `SUM` becoming `numeric` (and is `integer` at the moment), we'll explicitly convert it here, so as to avoid the warning from `data.table`). And then we'll set the key for join.

```
dat[, SUM := as.numeric(SUM)]
setkey(dat, COHORT)
```

We then create the `data.table` (a lookup) which has the values to divide by:

```
ii = data.table(COHORT=c("RA", "Lupus", "YRI", "CEU", "ASW"), 
                val = as.integer(c(62, 62, 80, 96, 5)))
```

And now, we perform the `join` as follows (Shown here for both current CRAN version and future data.table versions):

```
dat[ii, SUM := SUM/val]            ## v <= 1.9.2 - implicit by or by-without-by

dat[ii, SUM := SUM/val, by=.EACHI] ## v >= 1.9.3 - explicit by
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use a lookup vector:

```
#some sample data
set.seed(101)
DF = data.frame(COHORT = sample(c("RA", "Lupus", "YRI", "CEU", "ASW"), 1e5, T), 
                SUM = 1)
#> head(DF)
#COHORT SUM
#1  Lupus   1
#2     RA   1
#3    CEU   1
#4    CEU   1
#5  Lupus   1
#6  Lupus   1

lookup = c(62, 62, 80, 96, 5)
names(lookup) = c("RA", "Lupus", "YRI", "CEU", "ASW")
lookup
# RA Lupus   YRI   CEU   ASW 
# 62    62    80    96     5
```

and then match your "COHORT" to it:

```
ans1 = DF$SUM / unname(lookup[match(DF$COHORT, names(lookup))])
```

Compare it to yours:

```
ans2 = with(DF, 
     ifelse(COHORT == "RA", SUM / 62,
            ifelse(COHORT == "Lupus", SUM / 62,
                   ifelse(COHORT == "CEU", SUM / 96,
                          ifelse(COHORT == "YRI", SUM / 80,
                                 ifelse(COHORT == "ASW", SUM / 5, NA))))))
identical(ans1, ans2)
#[1] TRUE
```

And some benchmarkings:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ans1 = {lookup = c(62, 62, 80, 96, 5);
                       names(lookup) = c("RA", "Lupus", "YRI", "CEU", "ASW");
                       DF$SUM / unname(lookup[match(DF$COHORT, names(lookup))])},
               ans2 = with(DF, 
                           ifelse(COHORT == "RA", SUM / 62,
                           ifelse(COHORT == "Lupus", SUM / 62,
                           ifelse(COHORT == "CEU", SUM / 96,
                           ifelse(COHORT == "YRI", SUM / 80,
                           ifelse(COHORT == "ASW", SUM / 5, NA)))))),
               times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
# ans1   6.398761   6.604084   6.646192   6.984801   8.790249    10
# ans2 126.283224 129.819299 164.598707 167.435119 167.830104    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Agstudy's comment and more searching:

```
with(ITGAMnovelvarsDTSUM, ifelse(COHORT=="RA", SUM/62,ifelse(COHORT=="Lupus",SUM/62,ifelse(COHORT=="CEU",SUM/96,ifelse(COHORT=="YRI",SUM/5,ifelse(COHORT=="ASW",SUM/5,NA))))))
```